# RXJava Observable Operator from list to list of HashMap

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2

I have an array of Observable. I need to output a List of HashMap. But I am only getting one element of the array in the output.

If input is `[1,2,3,4]`

Output should be `{"results":[1,2,3,4]}`

I have the below:

```
result.flatMap(asyncN1qlQueryResult ->
  asyncN1qlQueryResult.errors().flatMap(error -> {
    return Observable
      .error(new Exception("unable to execute n1ql query " + error.toString()));
  })
  .switchIfEmpty(asyncN1qlQueryResult.rows())
).map(row -> {
    JsonObject json = ((AsyncN1qlQueryRow) row).value();
    return json;
  }).map(json -> {
    sbResults.append(json.toString());
    sbResults.append(",");log.info(" sbresults : " + sbResults.toString());
    return sbResults;
  })
  .map(results -> {
    resultMap.put("results", results.toString());
    return resultMap;
  });
```

THis does not seem to work because I am only getting a single element in the output.

Comment: Where does sbResults come from? Is it a global variable? Could you please specify the input values, and which values should be emitted by the observable. I do not really get, what values will go through the operators.

Comment: Writing functional code and mixing with mutable variables goes against the functional programming paradigm. From the look of this code you have nested `Observable` objects, which doesn't make sense.